# Dealing with dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has two date columns - Start Date and End Date,

Let's suppose start date is 4/10/2019 and end date is 4/10/2020 (MM/DD/YYYY) now I want to split these dates in a list which will have all the intermediate months (from october 2019 to october 2020). Is there any function in python that can hep me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can likely use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) as follows assuming your columns are called `start` and `end`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["start"], x["end"]), axis=1)
```